The zsh v5.9 on OSX v15.1 fails on tests like [[ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]]
Helping a friend who has a Mac, knows nothing about shell programming. Hopefully someone with access to zsh 5.9 on OSX 15.1 (or later) has a solution. I've checked this in older versions of OSX and zsh on an ancient Macbook Air and they all work.
What works on bash:
[[ -n $SSH_AGENT_PID ]] || exec ssh-agent $SHELL --login;
This used to work on zsh:
[[ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]] || exec ssh-agent $SHELL --login;
but fails with a nasthgram "undefined varaible" and doesn't
fall through to the exec statement on the new zsh 5.9.
I've tried defaulting or assigning the variable:
[[ -n "${SSH_AGENT_PID:-''}"  ]] || ...
[[ -n "${SSH_AGENT_PID:=''}" ]] || ...
No luck, these give me an "invalid modifier" error for each.
Q: Does anyone with access to zsh 5.9 on OSX 15.1 have some
way to avoid the 'undefined variable' in testing a    variable for being empty?
Searching for variations on "osx 15.1 zsh 5.9 undefined variable test" keeps getting me results from years ago that aren't for the current OSX. I'm guessing there is some setting in .zshlogin or .zshrc or built into the zsh startup that is setting the shell to blow up on undef var's but I don't know where to change it. Apple has been steadily locking down OSX, so this just seems like one more game they are playing with our heads.
Any assistance would be most appreciated.
Thank you
[[ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]] || exec ssh-agent $SHELL --login;
Should have tested the SSH_AGENT_PID variable for being empty and executed ssh-agent with the current shell if it were.
What I'm getting is an "undefined variable" error message that prevents falling through to the "|| exec..." half of it which starts ssh-agent.

What is the exact error message? The shell can be set to require variables to be set with setopt nounset, but the message that results (zsh 5.9, macos 13.7.1) is zsh: SSH_AGENT_PID: parameter not set. An undefined variable message may be coming from something else.

nasthgram "undefined varaible" what is a "nasthgram"?

Something to test with: you can start a completely clean zsh instance (no variables carried through, no startup files) with /usr/bin/env -i /bin/zsh -f. BTW, changing shell behavior at such a basic level would break a tremendous number of shell scripts; I doubt that such an action by Apple would have gone unnoticed.

@KamilCuk given the misspelled 'varaible', it might be a typo for 'nastygram'.

The command should work fine, and the quotes are unnecessary. I don't think that your zsh 5.9 really produces this error message on that statement. Show a screenshot which proves your point. In any case, check whether the variable SHELL has a reasonable value; maybe there is some garbage in it.
